# Diferencia y analogía entre lenguajes ensamblador (Nasm y Fasm)

Tags: ensamblador, lenguaje-agnóstico

Me explico, según lo que anuncié en el título de la pregunta.

Entre `Nasm` ([Netwide Assembler](https://www.nasm.us/)) y `Fasm` ([Flat Assembler](https://flatassembler.net/)). He leído en foros que `Fasm` es más rápido en la compilación de código, además crea archivos objeto más pequeños, y justamente éste mismo leguaje está programado en ensamblador y es auto compilable; así mismo, los detractores de `Nasm`, aseguran que está hecho en lenguaje `C` y esa es una de las características que le hacen menos competitivo al lenguaje ensamblador comparado en está pregunta.
Quizá esté equivocado, pero me parece entender que los ensambladores, que manejan, por decirlo de alguna manera, la última frontera más profunda de programación, tienen sus diferencias, análogas a `C++` y `Python`, sabiendo, por supuesto que en esta analogía,  uno es compilado y el otro interpretado respectivamente; pero haciendome entender.

Comment: tengo una duda existencial.. si programas en assembler, no compilas.. ya esta compilado... o sea, estos son pseudo lenguajes parecidos a assembler??? diferencias y analogias parece una pregunta enorme... ya que estuviste investigando, que descubriste????

Comment: Hola orcaval, la respuesta a tu pregunta estaría basada en opiniones, por lo que seguramente será cerrada, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: @MarcePuente dudo que diferencias o analogias sean basada en opiniones....

Comment: @gbianchi-enhuelga, entiendo, yo no tengo dudas.

Comment: yo lo dije por tu comentario... la respuesta, estaria basada en opiniones???? @MarcePuente???

Comment: Hay algo de mito en lo referente a Assembler y sus prestaciones. Dejo acá un video que lo explica https://youtu.be/pSvSXBorw4A?t=779

Comment: No me parece que la pregunta sea clara. Aparentemente quieres saber la diferencia entre NASM y FASM. Tómate un momento, piensa bien la pregunta y discierne lo esencial. Luego edita tu pregunta y usa espacios para mejorar su apariencia además de su contenido.